# Correct way to hint that a class is implementing a Protocol?

Tags: python, unit-testing, typing

On a path of improvement for my Python dev work. I have interest in testing interfaces defined with Protocol at CI/deb building time, so that if a interface isn't actually implemented by a class we will know immediately after the unit tests run.

My approach was typing with Protocol and using implements runtime_checkable to build unit test.   That works, but the team got into a little debate about how to *indicate* a concretion was implementing a Protocol without busting runtime_checkable. In C++/Java you need inheritance to indicate implementations of interfaces, but with Python you don't necessarily need inheritance.  The conversation centered on whether we should be inheriting from a Protocol interface class.

Consider this code example at the end which provides most of the gist of the question. We were thinking about Shape and indicating how to hint to a future developer that Shape is providing IShape, but doing so with inheritance makes the runtime_checkable version of isinstance unusable for its purpose in unit-testing.

There is a couple of paths to improvement here:

We could find a better way to hint that Shape implements IShape which doesn't involve direct inheritance.
We could find a better way to check if an interface is implemented at test deb package build time. Maybe runtime_checkable is the wrong idea.

Anyone got guidance on how to use Python better?
Thanks!

```
from typing import (
    Protocol,
    runtime_checkable
)
import dataclasses

@runtime_checkable
class IShape(Protocol):
    x: float


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Shape(IShape):
    foo:float = 0.

s  = Shape()
# evaluates as True but doesnt provide the interface. Undermines the point of the run-time checkable in unit testing
assert isinstance(s, IShape)
print(s.x)  # Error.  Interface wasnt implemented




#
# Contrast with this assert
#
@dataclasses.dataclass
class Goo():
    x:float = 1

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Hoo():
    foo: float = 1

g = Goo()
h = Hoo()
assert isinstance(g, IShape)  # asserts as true
# but because it has the interface and not because we inherited.
print(g.x)


assert isinstance(h, IShape)  # asserts as False which is what we want
```

Comment: Well, that's super cool! Thanks for asking this question, I just learned about `typing.Protocol`. As documented here https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#defining-a-protocol the point is to support static checking of duck typing, which means no, you don't subclass, something will pass the `ininstance` test if they implement the protocol.

Comment: I was familiar with abstract base classes (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) but I didn't know you could define your own with `typing.Protocol`.

Comment: To answer your question, `Goo` and `Hoo` are the right way to implement/not implement the `IShape` protocol.

Comment: A protocol is not an abstract base class; it's Python's implemenation of structural subtyping for static type checking. (Subclassing, on the other hand, is a form of *nominal* subtyping.)

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the clarification. I'm still learning this stuff. And thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: Do you use a type checker? If yes, then there is much simpler way comparing to runtime assertions: just leave this checks to type checker with explicit inheritance.

Comment: I do use a type checker in modules, but the actual driver predates bringing in the mypy type checker and isn't in type checking yet, so "def do_shapely_things(s:IShape):" will check fine in the module it is in.  You make a good point, though, if we got the legacy driver under type checking it should be able to find the mismatches with very little additional work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When talking about static type checking, it helps to understand the notion of a subtype as distinct from a subclass. (In Python, type and class are synonymous; not so in the type system implemented by tools like `mypy`.)

A type `T` is a *nominal* subtype of type `S` if we explicitly say it is. Subclassing is a form of nominal subtyping: `T` is a subtype of `S` if (but not *only* if) `T` is a subclass of `S`.

A type `T` is a *structural* subtype of type `S` if it something about `T` itself is compatible with `S`. Protocols are Python's implementation of structure subtyping. `Shape` does not not need to be a nominal subtype of `IShape` (via subclassing) in order to be a structural subtype of `IShape` (via having an `x` attribute).

So the point of defining `IShape` as a `Protocol` rather than just a superclass of `Shape` is to support structural subtyping and avoid the need for nominal subtyping (and all the problems that inheritance can introduce).

```
class IShape(Protocol):
    x: float


# A structural subtype of IShape
# Not a nominal subtype of IShape
class Shape:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 3

# Not a structural subtype of IShape
class Unshapely:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


def foo(v: IShape):
    pass

foo(Shape())  # OK
foo(Unshapely())  # Not OK
```

---

So is structural subtyping a replacement for nominal subtyping? Not at all. Inheritance has its uses, but when it's your *only* method of subtyping, it gets used inappropriately. Once you have a distinction between structural and nominal subtyping in your type system, you can use the one that is appropriate to your actual needs.

Comment: Btw, [PEP544](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#explicitly-declaring-implementation) mentions subclassing as a way to explicitly declare the new class as implementing the protocol. Another one important thing here is actual inheritance of protocol members, which can be used similarly to ABC (protocol may provide default attribute value or method implementation). If you inherit from protocol, `mypy` can detect incompatible attributes on static analysis step without `runtime_checkable`.

Comment: @chepner I assume mypy would tell you that `foo(Shape())` is OK but `foo(Unshapely())` is not, right?  -- just tested it, and yes, it does. That's good, and what I expected. And `isinstance` also behaves as expected. I know I'm repeating myself, but this is really cool stuff!

Comment: This is the correct answer imo but the world needs a PEP that says you can type hint an implementation of an interface e.g. this reads as "Class shape provides structural typing IShape"
```
class Shape() -> IShape:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 3
```
What that would buy the world is: 
1) mypy would be able to type check that Shape implements an interface even without a calling function being written yet, and it wouldn't be as strict or mismatched to the task as inheritance.  
2) future devs would know without a code comment that Shape implements IShape.

Comment: @jrounds But that's just nominal subtyping using different syntax; you may as well just inherit from `Protocol`. One thing that `Protocol` supplies is what PEP-544 calls *implicit* subtyping, where your type with an `x` attribute is a subtype of `IShape` whether you know `IShape` exists or not.

Comment: You convinced me to use abc.ABC if we want to be that explicit.  I also looked around on the internet and there is some pretty interesting discussions about abc vs Protocol, but out of scope for this conversation!  Thanks for your time.

Comment: @jrounds as STerliakov says PEP544 "mentions subclassing as a way to explicitly declare the new class as implementing the protocol". There's no need to use abc.ABC only to ahieve that